# define a integer type of data but return a string type data with node.js model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

i defined some data in integer type in my node.js models:

```js
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Comments = sequelize.define('Comments', {
        id : {type : DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement : true, primaryKey : true, unique : true},
        comment:{type:DataTypes.STRING},
        content:{type:DataTypes.STRING},
        professional: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER},//专业
        attitude: {type:DataTypes.INTEGER},//态度
        satisfaction:{type:DataTypes.INTEGER}//满意度

    },{
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Comments.belongsTo(models.Appointment);
                Comments.belongsTo(models.User,{as:"teacher"});
                Comments.belongsTo(models.User,{as:"student"});
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    return Comments;
}
```

,but after i create a new model with sequelize

```js
    this.addComment = function(model) {
      return models.Comments.create(model);
    }
```

data return become strings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmOfm.png)

can anyone explain that`s why? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's weird because your code is correct,i've hade such results, check out https://github.com/finfort/SequelizeTestRepo [image]

Comment: thank you ,I hade found the reason,that`s because data in model returns without handle by the sequelize